# XmlSerializer.Serialize base end node broken

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am serializing object into xml stream in C# .net 4. 
its hosted on windows server 2008 R2.
When I export xml file accessing that site locally, it exports broken end node like < /pr
When I export xml file accessing same site but from remote client any browser, it works completely fine.
Is anyone aware of any such settings on windows server or browser that might be causing this problem?

Lines of code which serialize are as below

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
System.IO.Stream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(st, object);
```

Comment: will you post your code how you do the serialization?

Comment: I have just updated my question with code

Comment: You probably need to flush the streeam to get all the data or you are using wrong encoding.  Streams default to ASCII which often changes data and add nulls.  Use UTF8 instead.